# How to get a control by name

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm struggling to get the right context with how to get a `TextBox` currently in my form.

Right now I have a button that when pressed will allow the user to choose a folder.  I'd like to take that path and put it in a `TextBox` which is currently named `installPath`.

```
namespace CustomLauncher
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void browse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //browse to select a folder
            FolderBrowserDialog folder = new FolderBrowserDialog();
            DialogResult result = folder.ShowDialog();
            if (result == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You chose" + folder.SelectedPath);
            }
            else if (result == DialogResult.Cancel)
            {
                return;
            }
        }
```

I've seen various attempts like...

`this.Controls.Find("installPath");` //visual studio didn't like this

`Control myControl1 = FindControl("installPath");` //didn't like this either

I've also seen a few other ways of doing this.  Though I can't seem to find one that visual studio will accept.  I feel like I'm missing something rather obvious/huge about the context of this event listener which is why I'm not able to figure out how to accomplish this.

Comment: Why not `this.installPath.Text = folder.SelectedPath`? Btw, you've seen the `FindControl` approaches  on ASP.NET sites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not `this.installPath.Text = folder.SelectedPath`? Is the `TextBox` on another form?

Btw, you've seen the `FindControl` approaches  on ASP.NET sites.

If you're using .NET 2 or greater you can use the [`Control.ControlCollection.Find` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

```
TextBox txtInstallPath = (TextBox)this.Controls.Find("installPath", true)[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code:

```
private void browse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //browse to select a folder
    FolderBrowserDialog folder = new FolderBrowserDialog();
    DialogResult result = folder.ShowDialog();
    if (result == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        installPath.Text = folder.SelectedPath;
        MessageBox.Show("You chose" + folder.SelectedPath);
    }
    else if (result == DialogResult.Cancel)
    {
        return;
    }
}
```